# Generate Binomial Permutations in Pandas

Tags: pandas, permutation

I have some taps. There are n of them. Each tap can either be off or on. I would like to generate a dataframe of all of the possible states that my set of taps could be in. For example if

```
n=2
```

Then I would like to generate the dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from  itertools import product

n = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(range(2), repeat=n)))

print (df)
   0  1
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
```

Comment: That works for n=2 but not for other values as it always has only 2 columns.

Comment: @R.Cox - so you need `df = pd.DataFrame(product(range(n), repeat=n))` ?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(range(2), repeat=n)))